# Matrix multiplication for multidimensional matrix (/array) - how to avoid loop?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to evaluate a matrix multiplication with arrays containing multiple matrices to be multiplied together. This can easily be achieved with two matrices using np.dot (or the new @ operator in Py3.5 +), but I'm struggling to extend this to efficiently evaluate my multidimensional arrays.

As an example, let's say I have matrix A with shape (5,3,3) and B with shape (5,3). Now, I want to matrix multiple the later parts for each 5 cases: i.e. do

```
res[0] = np.dot(A[0], B[0])
res[1] = np.dot(A[1], B[1])
etc
```

I can successfully achieve this using a loop - e.g.:

```
A = np.random.random((5,3,3))
B = np.random.random((5,3))

res = np.zeros([5,3])

for i in range(len(A)):
    res[i] = np.dot(A[i], B[i])
```

althoug this is slow because it uses a loop.

Is there a function / approach I could take to fully vectorize this please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
np.einsum('ijk,ik->ij',A,B)
```

Using [`np.matmul`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) -

```
np.matmul(A,B[...,None]).squeeze()
np.matmul(A,B[...,None])[...,0]
```

Comment: Thanks. Einsum sounds like the most efficient. I just need to get my head round how it works now...

Comment: There are sometimes *faster* ways to do tensor calculations than `einsum`, but none *clearer*.  I used to be a doubter like John below, but Divakar has made me a believer.

Comment: @DanielForsman Yup! There are trade-offs mostly based on the shapes of the input arrays involved and in it the axes lengths of the sum-reductions. There's a lot of playing around involved with it, its fun!

Answer (score 2):

Also, using sum and broadcasting:

```
np.sum(A * B[:, np.newaxis, :], axis=2)
```

Einsum seems to be the fastest option though.
This would be the slowest since it instantiate the product of elements.

Answer (score 1):

Because I always have a hard time understanding `einsum()`, I came up with this:

```
np.diagonal(np.squeeze(np.dot(A, B[:,:,None])), axis2=2).T
```

It works, and it has no loops, but it is significantly slower than `einsum()` because of the `:,:,None` expansion of `B` from 2D to 3D (which is later reduced by `diagonal()`).  I'm not sure if there's a way to make this more compact.

Comment: This is a case where the newish `matmul` (`@`) is a big improvement.  As Divakar shows it still requires expanding `B`, but it doesn't require throwing out a lot of extra calculations with `diagonal`.  `squeeze` is cheap.